# How to easily pull strings out of a file and store in variables?

Tags: shell, parsing

I think I'm looking at awk vs PHP vs Perl vs cut. Maybe.

I want to look at `wp-config.php` and look at these lines:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'mydb');
define('DB_USER', 'myuser');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xx');
```

And pull out the strings "mydb" and "myuser" and the password, so I can do something with it, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/sh

..insert magical code here to store strings into DBNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD...
mysqldump -u $USERNAME -p$PASSWORD $DBNAME > /tmp/blah.sql
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could write your script in PHP and simply include the config file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is quick and dirty `awk` hack:

`awk -F "'" '{print $4}' wp-config.php`

You can also try `cut`:

`cut -d"'" -f 4 wp-config.php`

EDIT: to set variables this should work:

```
USERNAME=`grep DB_NAME wp-config.php | awk -F "'" '{print $4}'`
```

And so on..

Comment: Ok, the awk line works. But how do I get the results into those variables?